# how to slide a menu in with fix header

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

i am trying to implement a sliding menu,i am using j-Query Mobile in which i am using panel widget and sliding of menu takes place on button click,i have a problem that whenever i click the button the header moves along with it when the menu slides in,i tried using fixed header but it is also not working,here is my code snippet

```
<div data-role="header" id="head" >
        <h1 align="center">HEADACHE APP </h1>
    </div>

    <!--Header Ends-->

    <!--        Panel-->

    <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" >
        <a href="iheadache.html" data-role="button">hello</a>

     </div>
     <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-mini" id="menubtn">menu</a>
```

Comment: add `data-display="overlay"` to panel div. `push` and `reveal` will move header.